# FLAG=-DNDEBUG is not disabling assert() in C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, assert

I have a bunch of `assert()` functions I used throughout my C files and from [reading](http://codeyarns.com/2015/03/16/how-to-disable-assert-in-gcc/) I have done I should be able to disable the assertions by passing in a command line parameter like so:

```
make
```

Doing this does not disable the assertions. However, adding into the code, `#define NDEBUG` does disable the assertions. I want to disable them from the command line though. Is there a reason why this flag is not working correctly?

I am on a Windows machine.

Here is the makefile:

```
OPTIONS = -B CFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror

a.out: myProgram.o StudentImplementation.o ListImplementation.o
    gcc $(OPTIONS) myProgram.o StudentImplementation.o ListImplementation.o

myProgram.o: myProgram.c StudentInterface.h StudentType.h ListInterface.h ListType.h
    gcc $(OPTIONS) -c myProgram.c

StudentImplementation.o: StudentImplementation.c StudentInterface.h StudentType.h
    gcc $(OPTIONS) -c StudentImplementation.c

ListImplementation.o: ListImplementation.c ListInterface.h ListType.h StudentInterface.h StudentType.h
    gcc $(OPTIONS) -c ListImplementation.c

clean:
    rm *.o a.out
```

Comment: @PaulR no, there is no FLAG in it. Here is what my options line looks like: `OPTIONS = -B CFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror`

Comment: @PaulR I added the makefile.

Comment: @PaulR I edited my question. The makefile that I added included the parameter in the makefile directly instead of via the command line. When running it was actually doing just `make`

Comment: @jayant that way is probably too far from what my professor expects. I will  go with the way rici has posted as it is working for me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a normal makefile or no makefile, then the command you want is

```
make -B CFLAGS=-DNDEBUG
```

There is no `FLAG` variable in the standard make recipes; each component has its own variable, so `CFLAGS` is for C, `CXXFLAGS` is for C++, `LDFLAGS` is for the linker, and so on.

With the `Makefile` you provide in the question, you cannot change flags on the `make` command line. You could use

```
OPTIONS = -DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror
```

but that means editing your Makefile every time you want to change the debug setting.

Comment: Interesting, that was the exact command the professor also gave us to use (with the FLAG one). I tried the way you suggested and had no success either. I also tried just directly adding it to the options in my makefile and it still did not work: `OPTIONS = -B CFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror`

Comment: @Fogest: it would help if you included your actual Makefile in your question.

Comment: I have now added it to the question.

Comment: @Fogest: You shouldn't use `-B` as a gcc option. (And the gcc option is just `-DNDEBUG`, don't put CFLAGS in that line.) I would think that providing that pair of gcc options would cause the compile to fail.

Comment: That was it. I am now using `make -B` and the `-DNDEBUG` is in the make file. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need

```
OPTIONS = -DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic...
```

However a simpler Makefile would look like this

```
CFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror -I.

a.out: myProgram.o StudentImplementation.o ListImplementation.o

clean:
    rm *.o a.out
```

Comment: Did you clean before make? Were there any errors in compilation?

Comment: Yes so the build looks good. Can you show how NDEBUG is used in the code?

Comment: `NDEBUG` is not used in the code. I used it in the code to test if using the define would work in the code, and it did work. I simply placed a `#define NDEBUG` directly before the `#include <assert.h>` in the code.

Comment: I think you need to take the `-B` out - it doesn't belong here and it's swallowing the next parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Unix makefile experience, the default flag should be CFLAGS, unless of course FLAG is explicitly used in your makefile. However, defining CFLAGS on the command line is not recommended since it is [overriding a make variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html).

Are there any [-DNDEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) in the compiler call invocations? If not, perhaps the problem lies in the Makefile itself, and you will have to provide its relevant data.

Comment: You dont relay on implicit rulesto compile your code. ThereforeCFLAGS is irrelevanz. Please use a variable to hold that specific define. Lets say ASSERTDEF, and override it in the commandline. Then add variable content to to OPTIONS.

Comment: Are you referring to using a `#define` within the code? Because I am specifically told in this assignment that I am not allowed to use a `#define` to toggle the debug state.

Comment: command line: make -B "ASSERTDEF=-DNDEBUG". your OPTIONS should be defined like this: OPTIONS := $(ASSERTDEF) $(OTHER_VARIABLES). make sure the review the gcc executions! if you don´t see the -DDNDEBUG, then something is fishy.